Resizeable rectangle on a map
Using ipyleaflet, I put a rectangle on a map and I have a callback when I move the shape around but I don't figure out how to add a callback when I resize the same shape. Any idea ? Ultimately I would like the example to work with Shiny for Python
Here's  a short example:
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles, Rectangle

def handle_click(**kwargs):
    print("On click: ", kwargs)


watercolor = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.Stadia.StamenTerrain)

m = Map(layers=(watercolor, ), center=(50, 354), zoom=5)


rectangle = Rectangle(bounds=([50,354],[51,355] ), name='aoi', draggable=True, transform=True, rotation=False)
rectangle.on_click(handle_click)

m.add(rectangle)

m


You can use the observe pattern to observe the locations trait of Rectangle, which is inherited from Polyline (see here and follow back to Polygon, then Polyline).
def on_change(change):
    print(change.new)

rectangle.observe(on_change, 'locations')


